# Removing blank line from end of result in java

Tags: java

This is what my result looks like:

```
1.*********
2.*********
3.*********
4.*********
5.*********
6.*********
7.
```

I need to remove the blank line 7

**Here is my code:**

```
public static String getRectangle(int maxRows, int maxCols, char symbol) {
    new UnsupportedOperationException("You must implement this method.");
    if (maxRows<1 || maxCols<1) { 
        return null; 
    } else { 
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < maxRows; i++) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < maxCols; j++) { 
                result = result + symbol;
            } 
            result = result + "\n";
        } 
        return result;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any extra conditions. Just replace `return result` with `return result.trim()`

Answer (score 3):

Add a condition here:

```
if (i != maxRows - 1) {
    result = result + "\n";
}
```

Although i would suggest using a StringBuilder instead of a string to store the result.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Java version wasn't specified, as of **Java 11**, you can use [`String::repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) with amended number of rows and columns:

```
public static String getRectangle(int maxRows, int maxCols, char symbol) {
    if (maxRows<1 || maxCols<1) {
        return null;
    } else {
        String row = String.valueOf(symbol).repeat(maxCols);  // create a row
        String columns = (row + "\n").repeat(maxRows - 1);    // create n-1 columns 
        return columns + row;                                 // append the last column 
                                                              // .. without the new line
    }
}
```

If you are stick with a **lower version of Java**, use `StringBuilder`. The advantage of this class is they can be used with each other:

```
public static String getRectangle(int maxRows, int maxCols, char symbol) {
    if (maxRows<1 || maxCols<1) {
        return null;
    } else {
        StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder column = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < maxCols; i++) {        // rows
            row.append(symbol);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < maxRows - 1; i++) {    // n-1 columns
            column.append(row).append("\n");
        }
        return column.append(row).toString();      // append the last one w/o a new line
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a simple condition will help

```
    public static String getRectangle(int maxRows, int maxCols, char symbol) {
//        new UnsupportedOperationException("You must implement this method.");
        if (maxRows < 1 || maxCols < 1) {
            return null;
        } else {
            String result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < maxRows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < maxCols; j++) {
                    result = result + symbol;
                }
                if (i != maxRows - 1) result = result + "\n";
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to build a repeated rectangle without the trailing new line is to use combination of ancient `Collections.nCopies` and `String.join` (Java 8+):

```java
public static String getRectangle(int maxRows, int maxCols, char symbol) {
    if (maxRows<1 || maxCols<1) {
        return null;
    }
    String row = String.join("", Collection.nCopies(maxCols, String.valueOf(symbol)));
    return String.join("\n", Collections.nCopies(maxRows, row));                                
}
```